# convert user input to JavaScript object

Tags: object, input

I'd like to convert the user input into an object 
ex:if user enter in the input box :
{ id: 11, pId: 1, name: "xyz" },
{ id: 111, pId: 11, name: "abc" }

convert to 2 objects

Comment: Please add what you tried so far and what failed.

Comment: '$("#generate").click(function () {
        if ($("#jsonData").val() == "") {
            zNodes = [
                     { id: 1, pId: 0, name: "LEVEL 1", expand: false },
                     { id: 11, pId: 1, name: "ClientSide" }                  
            ];
        }
        if ($("#jsonData").val() !== "") {
            //i want from user to enter the data 
            var a = $("#jsonData").val();                    
            var b = {a};            
            zNodes = [b];
        }'

Comment: do you expect, that someone will try to parse your comment, please edit your question... if you want that some helps you, you have to respect the effort to do so.

Answer (score 0):

this is my example:

$("#generate").click(function () {

```
    if ($("#jsonData").val() == "") {
        zNodes = [
                 { id: 1, pId: 0, name: "LEVEL 1", expand: false },
                 { id: 11, pId: 1, name: "ClientSide" }                  
        ];
    }
    if ($("#jsonData").val() !== "") {
        //i want from user to enter the data 
        var a = $("#jsonData").val();                    
        var b = {a};            
        zNodes = [b];
    }
```